# WebSphere database domain error, please help

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

Has anyone seen the following error before in Websphere 6.1 Portal?  What does it mean the database domain is currently unavailable?  I tested DB connections via the Websphere console and they all worked.  Not sure what database domain means.  We saw this for multiple domains.

0000009f DataStoreCont E com.ibm.wps.datastore.impl.DataStoreContext handleException EJPDB0002E: Error occurred during database access.
com.ibm.wps.datastore.domains.DomainUnavailableException: EJPDB0101E: Database domain [Domain: cust] is currently unavailable.
at com.ibm.wps.datastore.impl.DataStoreContext.handleException(DataStoreContext.java:315)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customization database holds information like users' private pages. In case they can access ie. shared settings their customized page becomes a new private version of the page. An other usage for the customization database are the portlet preferences. The database domain unavailable error message is a very generic way of telling that the database can not be accessed.

As you saw the error messages for several domains I would say your database server crashed. The connection testing feature of WAS only tests connection - not that any queries actually succeed. Such error messages can also be caused by misconfigured HA solutions.